# Bash script passes syntax check, but errors out with missing ']'

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm putting together a simple backup script that will tar contents of a folder, then move that file to a backup server.  The script makes sure that the tar file exists and is not zero bytes before moving around.

The problem is that the script is dying on one of the IF lines

```
if [ -f /www/archives/pdf/pdf_201207021048.tar && 11294720 -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "tar file exists and is greater than 0 bytes."
else
    echo "tar file does not exist or is zero bytes"
fi
```

The error in the console is:

```
./backup_pdf.sh: line 49: [: missing `]'
```

Line 49 is the if statement above.

The script is successfully verified with

```
bash -n backup.sh
```

What's wrong that bash is seeing a missing ']', yet it passes the syntax check?

Comment: To be a little more specific about *why* it passes the syntax check -- `[` is a command, not syntax, and `bash -n` doesn't check whether you're passing `[` a correct set of arguments any more than it checks whether you're passing `rsync` or any other command correct arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The && operator separates commands, so your `[` and your `]` aren't part of the same command, as is required. Either use two sets of brackets with a && between them, or use the `-a` operator. Most people prefer the first option these days.

Comment: or use `[[` rather than the old Bourne shell syntax

Comment: It's not just preference -- the way `-a` is defined in POSIX, they can't be chained, so any support for `[ foo -a bar -a baz ]` is a non-standard extension.